# Reverse for 'post-detail' with keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'slug': 'long-establis

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add comment fields to my post-detail view. But as soon i add redirect url after calling save(). This gives me error something like this.

> Reverse for 'post-detail' with keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'slug': 'long-established-fact-that-a-reader-will'}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P[^/]+)/$']

this is my code

> posts/views.py

```
@login_required
def postDetail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    latest_post = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[0:4]
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect('post-detail', kwargs = {
                'slug': post.slug
            })
    context ={
        'form': form,
        'post': post,
        'latest_post': latest_post
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/post_detail.html', context)
```

> posts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from posts.views import index,postDetail, categoryDetail, blog, search

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="home"),
    path('blog/', blog, name="blog"),
    path('search/', search, name='search'),
    path('post/<str:slug>/', postDetail, name='post-detail'),
    path('category/<slug>/', categoryDetail, name='category-detail'),    
]
```

> posts/models.py

```
from tinymce import HTMLField
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from slugger import AutoSlugField
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
User = get_user_model()


def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.slug, filename)


class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    overview = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = HTMLField()
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_location,
        null=True, 
        blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    previous_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name= 'previous', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    next_post = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name= 'next', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    @property
    def get_comments(self):
        return self.comments.all().order_by('-timestamp')

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your 4th path, you used `<str:slug>` - I don't believe the URL catching type `str` catches the dashes used in slugs.

Try this path instead: `path('post/<slug:slug>/', postDetail, name='post-detail'),`

**EDIT**

You are also missing a `reverse` in your `postDetail()` redirect:

```
@login_required
def postDetail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    latest_post = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[0:4]
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('main:post-detail', kwargs = {
                'slug': post.slug
            }))
    context ={
        'form': form,
        'post': post,
        'latest_post': latest_post
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/post_detail.html', context)
```

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters

Comment: @adityakumar did you try adding an `app_name` above your urlpatterns, and then referincing it in the redirect? i.e. `app_name = 'main'`, `redirect('main:post-detail, ...)`

Comment: @adityakumar give it a shot like I wrote, restart your server, and let me know if it changes anything

Comment: after adding app_name, I can't even go to home url it says this. Reverse for 'blog' not found. 'blog' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: @adityakumar You will need to update all of your `reverse` urls to include the new namespace. i.e. `reverse('main:<url-name>)'`

Comment: def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

Comment: i did this for post-detail

Comment: Use: `def get_absolute_url(self): return reverse('main:post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})`

Comment: It looks like you also forgot to use `reverse` in your `postDetail()` view. I updated my answer to use the correct code - let me know if that works for you.